# rewriting a list of vectors to prove that another list is in the span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The problem I am working on is

suppose $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ span $V$ prove the list $v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3, v_3-v_4,v_4$ also spans $V$.

I understand that I have to write the second list as a linear combination of the first but don't understand the properties that allow me to group them.

Am I allowed to assume $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4 = 0$ or am I substituting the $v_1-v_2$ for $v_1$ and so on but have to leave $v_4$ so that it is still within the span?

I'm not looking for a completely worked out answer just a single step to understand which properties I can use.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can write $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4=0$ but you cannot conclude from this that $a_i=0$ since you don't know the $v_i$'s are linearly independent. Instead try this: you know any $v\in V$ is a linear combination of the $v_i's$. Now, write this linear combination as a linear combination of the differences and $v_4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are told that the span of $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ is $V$.  You want to show that the span of $v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3, v_3-v_4,v_4$ is also $V$.  One approach is for you to show that each of $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $v_1-v_2, v_2-v_3, v_3-v_4,v_4$.  For example, $v_1=(v_1-v_2)+(v_2-v_3)+(v_3-v_4)+v_4$, showing that $v_1$ is such a linear combination.